# fixing missing grubx64.efi and the grub menu rhel 7

Tags: centos, rhel, grub2, uefi

I had a work server, supermicro having EFI, fail to boot it's one hard disk having RHEL 7.6 x86-64 because of a missing `/boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grubx64.efi` file.

I am using a spare SSD on a spare computer, I installed RHEL 7.6 from DVD and had it working.  Then manually removed `/boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grubx64.efi` to replicate the problem.

my one disk having RHEL 7.6 installed on it is partitioned like this

```
/dev/sda1   XFS   /boot         1GB
/dev/sda2   EFI   /boot/efi   100MB
/dev/sda3   XFS   /             max
```

So far I have found I can recreate `grubx64.efi` by doing the following

- boot computer using the corresponding RHEL install dvd
- choose rescue mode
- follow prompts, eventually do a `chroot /mnt/sysimage` as it indicates in the menu prompts and I can then access anything on my disk
- `yum install grub2-efi-modules` otherwise the following command will error with *a something not found, there is a bugzilla stating not a bug.*
- `grub2-install   --target=x86_64-efi   --efi-directory=/boot/efi   --bootloader-id=redhat   --recheck`

That causes the `grubx64.efi` to reappear under the corresponding `bootloader-id` directory {as evident by my pic} so I want "redhat" here to keep the folder naming the way it was for RHEL.

I then do a `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg` and all seems well but after booting I get the grub text screen and do not know what to do at this point.

As shown by my pic below my working EFI choice is "redhat" for that ssd.  My other 2 disks are my win10 ssd and my centos ssd so ignore those.  So far I managed to create "red" and "crap" doing what I've done, I've deleted those corresponding */boot/efi/EFI/* folders but I guess they still show up as choices in my EFI screen menu.  Is there a way to correct or undo those no longer relevant items?

Biggest question is how do I get the GRUB2 screen back to saying what it traditionally should with the menu option, which is `RedHat Enterprise Linux` with the kernel name when choosing the correct `redhat` boot option?

[image: bios]
[image: grubtextscreen]